# Open lightbox and redirect parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lightbox

I'm wondering if it is possible to open a lightbox popup and redirect the parent page at the same time.
I have an ajax script that gets html as a response, i want to open a lightbox popup to show the html  but at the same time the parent windows should redirect to a specific page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done but not in the normal `document.reload()` way. Rather than that, you would have to ajax the parent page content, then manually append it to a container in the parent page while the light box is visible! this will not interrupt the light box, but change the content of the parent page! Will be a tricky thing to do but, achievable.